# Is there a property that styles margins and positions on the background (vm--overlay) of vue-js-modal?

Tags: vue.js, simplemodal

When vue-js-modal is set to modal Open, the DOM shown below is inserted.

```
<div class='modal'>
    <div class='vm--overlay'></div>
    <div class='modal-content'></div>
</div>
```

Since the header exists on the screen where the modal is inserted,

**I want to implement it so that it does not cover the header.**
*Or No need for it(`vm--overlay`).*

The structure of the DOM is as follows.

```
<header></header>
<div class='modal'>
    <div class='vm--overlay'></div>
    <div class='modal-content'></div>
</div>
```

I was able to apply styles to modal-content,
just like that below

```
.modal-content {
   // same value as header height
   margin-top: 50px;
}
```

But I couldn't apply the style against `vm--overlay`.

The following didn't work.

```
.vm--overlay {
   // same value as header height
   margin-top: 50px;
}
```

**Is there way to remove the `vm--overlay` or apply the style?**

it is a link of properties of `vue-js-modal`.

https://euvl.github.io/vue-js-modal/Properties.html#properties-2

Comment: Not sure but try this `.vm--overlay {margin-top: 50px !important}`

Comment: @localdev      Thank you for answer. Unfortunately, it wasn't well.